# Can I sacrifice an opponent's creature to Shadowborn Demon?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I have a [Shadowborn Demon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shadowborn%20Demon) and I was a little curious about the description of it. It specifically says "At the beginning of your upkeep, if there are fewer than six creature cards in your graveyard, sacrifice a creature."

So what I was wondering is, do I have to sacrifice my own creature? Or can I try and keep less than six creatures in my graveyard and sacrifice an opponent's creature every upkeep? Since it does specifically says "*a* creature" — it does not say "your creature" or "a creature you control." Most cards that have a sacrifice involved are extremely specific about that and will say "your creature" or "a creature you control" if it wants you to sacrifice your own creatures.

Comment: As a historical note, cards used to be worded "Sacrifice a creature you control", but with the new definition, it's now redundant.

Comment: @ikegami The exact wording was more like _"Sacrifice one of your creatures"_. You can find it on Sacrifice, for example. http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=sacrifice

Answer (score 15):

You cannot sacrifice a creature you do not control. The rule on sacrifice, 701.14a says

> To sacrifice a permanent, its controller moves it from the battlefield directly to its owner’s graveyard. **A player can’t sacrifice something that isn’t a permanent, or something that’s a permanent he or she doesn’t control**. Sacrificing a permanent doesn’t destroy it, so regeneration or other effects that replace destruction can’t affect this action.

From a common sense point of view, getting rid of something that's not yours isn't really a *sacrifice*.